# Populate an HTML DropDown List with data from mysql database without PHP

Tags: html, mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently building a rails app where im trying to fetch data from different tables from my sql database and I need to put that fetched data (id, first_name, last_name) into an HTML Drop-down where the user is going to select between all possible choices, for exemple:

DROPDOWN Clients:

### default:    --SELECT--

```
        1 Thomas Carrier
```

---

```
        2 Michel Carrier
```

---

```
        3 Yvon Dupuis
```

---

So if we take the first choice, 1 is the id of the first employee, and his first name (Thomas) and last name (Carrier)

I keep finding stuff about php but I cannot use php!

Thanks for the help

Comment: What can you use to fetch data ? Perl, Python, C, bash, Cobol... ?

Comment: My bad i forgot to mention im building a ruby on rails app right now, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The easy answer**

plain html

```html
<select name="clients">
    <option value="1">Thomas Carrier</option>
    <option value="2">Michel Carrier</option>
    ...
</select>
```

or with ruby (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

```rb
<select name="clients">
    <% @clients.each do |client| %>
        <option value="<%= client.id %>"><%= client.firstName %> <%= client.lastName %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

**Also refer to Yaniv Iny's answer to for a better more correct way**

Comment: Im glad this fixed it for you, please select the answer as the correct answer so future Stack overflow users can see it too

Answer (score 1):

this is another option which I think is more the "rails" way:

You should add this to your client.rb model:

```
def full_name
 first_name + ' ' + last_name
end
```

and then in your view something like this:

```
<%= select_tag("clients", options_from_collection_for_select(@clients, "id", "full_name"), include_blank: '--SELECT--') %>
```